# Who is Hafiz Salahuddin Yusuf?

Tags: hadith, islamic-scholar

Darussalam publishes a copy of [Riyad-us-Saliheen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/507739.Riyad_us_Saliheen) which, in addition to the actual ahadith compiled by Al-Nawawi, includes commentary by one Hafiz Salahuddin Yusuf.

The introduction to the collection provides no information on the commentator except that he had originally provided commentary on the Urdu collection.  It doesn't go into any details as to his credentials or education.

In other words, it doesn't give any indication that this commentary is any more or less useful than the commentary of any random user on the street.

Google searching provides next to nothing except that he's from Pakistan (no surprise, given that he's contributed to the Urdu collection), that he's involved with the Darussalam Research Division (no surprise, given that this is a Darussalam-published collection), and that he was also involved with Tafsir Ahsanul Bayan (also published by Darussalam).  Which really doesn't help except to suggest that the commentary was an in-house job (which doesn't necessarily impugn credibility, but in no way bolsters it either).

Who exactly is Hafiz Salahuddin Yusuf?  What experience/education/expertise does he have that equips him to provide a commentary on such a classic collection?  What, if anything, makes *his* commentary in any way valuable and/or useful?

Comment: Questions like "What, if anything, makes his commentary in any way valuable and/or useful?" attract solely opinions rather than good answers. Please feel free to refine it and make it more constructive.

Answer (score 2):

Haafiz Salaah-ud-Deen Yoosuf is Head of Darussalam's Research Division in Lahore.

He was formerly:
- Islamic Legal Consultant to the Federal Shariat Court of Pakistan, and
- Editor-in-Chief of al-I'tisaam magazine.

Answer (score 0):

Asalam o Alikum brothers and sister,

Hafiz Salahuddin Yusuf is a great scholar and had some appearance/lectures/interview on PeaceTV which is famous for it's spreading of Islam only based on Quran and Sahih Hadit (Hadees).

I also bought a book from my friends book shop (Ahsan ul Bayan). He recommended that it is authentic one.

But as my own curiosity, I also tried to find out some more about this person. I actually found his interview relating Zakat on youtube.com which PeaceTV on-aired as well.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5KDmW_ibMg

So, we can trust on his research and efforts... May Allah helps understand the religion and guide us and keep us stead fast on the right of those on whom HE showered his blessings.

AMEEN

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that we can trust him just because he appeared on PeaceTV? That was the primary question.

Answer (score -1):

He focussed pretty much to prove several ahadees Daeef included in the text of Riyadhussaliheen that suggest practice against the practices of Salafiyah, from which I concluded that he is trying to say that Imaam UL Nawawi had less understanding of which Hadeeth to include and which to not include in his book. I think he is a Salafiyah based Alim.
Wallahu alam