# What is brocade?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

I know that, as a man, I am banned from wearing various forms of clothing.  According to [a relevant fatwa on IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/158299), brocade is one such forbidden based on the following hadith:

> narrated by al-Bukhaari (5837) from Hudhayfah (may Allah be pleased with him) who said: The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) forbade us to wear silk and brocade and to sit on them.

What  I want to know is what is 'brocade'? I wish to avoid it, but without an image I'm finding it difficult.

When I search for '[brocade](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=brocade&sboxchip=Images&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=9zAoU-mrEIyS7AawuoH4CA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAA&biw=360&bih=567)' I see lots of different patterns and styles. Are these all haram? Is one particular design haram? Is it in combination with the material etc haram?

Comment: the hadith is about material. not about the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Hafiz Salahuddin Yusuf's](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11677/22) commentary on Riyadh al-Saliheen, *dibaj* (translated in your case as "brocade") refers to a particular kind of silk cloth, but there are different opinions as to exactly what it is.  He lists the following two:

1. A *thick* silk cloth, differentiated from normal silk cloth due to its weight.
2. A blended fabric, which contains some waft/weave threads that are made of silk but the remainder is cotton.

In both cases it's referring to the *fabric*, not the *pattern*, and in both cases, silk is a significant factor therein; most likely the prohibition is just a natural extension of the prohibition of silk itself.  So long as the fabric you're concerned about does not contain silk, it's not likely to fall under the (literal) definition of *dibaj*.